# Как сохранить локально рейтинг cosmos. Swift xCode

Tags: swift, xcode

Мне нужно сохранить выставленный ранее рейтинг, я так понимаю, что мне это нужно сделать через UserDefaults. Но у меня не получается это сделать. Я новичок в свифте, пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно это делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в принципе вы все правильно делаете, попробуйте вывести ваш ключ `print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “rateCosmosView”))`

Comment: @Marshall Вывести ключ не получается, потому что xCode выдает ошибку, что я не задала еще раз ключ. layer = <CALayer: 0x600000b65e40>> for key rateCosmosView' Его нужно куда-то ввести, но я не понимаю куда. Может во viewDidLoad?

Comment: я на сколько понимаю вы хотите сохранить весь этот класс `cosmosView`, советую вам делать так, `UserDefaults.standard.set("1", forKey: "rateCosmosView")`, затем где вам нужен этот класс вы пишите `if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “rateCosmosView”) == "1"{ *вызывайте ваш класс здесь(не нужно записывать весь класс в ud)*`}

Answer (score 0):

Как присвоить:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("ваше значение", forKey: "название ключа")
```

Обращение пример:

```
let name = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “name”)
  if  name == "easyVJ"{
print("cool")
}
```